# Angular 12 - how do you pass an object into your service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services, injection-tokens

I abstracted some functionality from a component into a separate service, and injected the service into my component in order to use it. The problem I am facing now is that within my service, I need access to an object in my component.

How do I pass this object into my service. Is there a way to inject this object with a custom InjectionToken?

Thanks for any help!

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-laszw4?file=src/app/app.module.ts) - commented out inflicting code in service

Comment: Maybe just pass the object as an argument to your service method: `service.doSomethingWithOrder(this.order);`  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-68868476?file=src/app/order/order.component.ts&devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to change this in your component:

```
  doSomething() {
    this.service.doSomethingWithOrder(this.order);
  }
```

and this in your service:

```
doSomethingWithOrder(order: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }) {
    console.log(order.name);
    alert('need access to order here');
  }
```

but be careful! As it's an object, you pass it as reference. If you modify it in the service, you are modifying the component object as well (the same instance).

Comment: Thanks, this simple solution is all I needed. I created a setter method within the service and can now use the object where I need it. Cheers!